# Fail fast function chaining

Tags: scala

Wondering if there is a better technique to implement a function chaining on `Any` that will stop the chain if an `APIException` Object is encountered (doesn't have to extend `Throwable` or `Exception`, or use `throw`). Also, would prefer not to use `scalaz` (makes my head spin)

1. Chaining function should carry `APIException` through to the end and return it.
2. Chaining function doesn't have to carry intermediate results to the end, except for the output from the last block.

Here is a test spec:

```
class FailFastChainSpec extends PlaySpec {

  import utils.Ops._

  def fFailsValidation(): Option[APIException] = Some(UnknownException())

  def fPassesValidation(): Option[APIException] = None

  def someCalculation = "Results"

  "Utils" when {

    "FailFastChaining" must {
      "return Left(APIException) when encountered (at beginning of chain)" in {
        fFailsValidation |> {
          someCalculation
        } mustBe Left(UnknownException())
      }

      "return Right(...) when no APIExceptions are encountered" in {
        fPassesValidation |> {
          someCalculation
        } mustBe Right(someCalculation)
      }

      "return Left(APIException) when encountered (in middle of chain with 1 link)" in {
        fPassesValidation |> fFailsValidation mustBe Left(UnknownException())
      }

      "return Left(APIException) when encountered (at end of chain with 1 link)" in {
        fPassesValidation |> {
          Left(UnknownException())
        } mustBe Left(UnknownException())
      }

      "return Left(APIException) when encountered (at end of chain with 2 links)" in {
        fPassesValidation |> fPassesValidation |> {
          Left(UnknownException())
        } mustBe Left(UnknownException())
      }

      "return Right(...) when no APIExceptions are encountered (multiple links)" in {
        fPassesValidation |> fPassesValidation |> fPassesValidation |> fPassesValidation |> {
          Right(someCalculation)
        } mustBe Right(someCalculation)
      }

      "return Right(...) when no APIExceptions are encountered (complex multiple links)" in {
        fPassesValidation |> fPassesValidation |> {
          Right("Cupcakes")
        } |> fPassesValidation |> {
          Right(someCalculation)
        } mustBe Right(someCalculation)
      }

    }

  }
}
```

Here is a an implementation I came up with, looking for improvements on this.

```
object Ops {

  implicit def anyToAny[A](o: A): AnyOps[A] = new AnyOps[A](o)

  class AnyOps[A](val a: A) {
    def chain[B, C, D](c: C): Either[B, D] = |>[B,C,D](c)

    def |>[B, C, D](c: C): Either[B, D] = {
      a match {
        case Some(v: APIException) => Left(v.asInstanceOf[B])
        case v: APIException => Left(v.asInstanceOf[B])
        case Left(v) => Left(v.asInstanceOf[B])
        case _ => c match {
          case Some(v: APIException) => Left(v.asInstanceOf[B])
          case v: APIException => Left(v.asInstanceOf[B])
          case Left(v) => Left(v.asInstanceOf[B])
          case Right(v) => Right(v.asInstanceOf[D])
          case v => Right(v.asInstanceOf[D])
        }
      }
    }
  }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you combine the `Option` type with a for comprehension, then you can emulate monadic behavior:

```
  import scala.util.control.Exception._
  import scala.util._

  def dangerousOp = throw new RuntimeException("never works")

  def f1(s: Int): Try[Int] = Success(s * 10)
  def f2(s: Int): Try[Int] = catching(classOf[Exception]) toTry dangerousOp
  def f3(s: Int): Try[Int] = Success(s * 30)

  val result = for {
    x <- f1(10)
    y <- f2(x)
    z <- f3(y)
  } yield z

  println(result) // Failure(java.lang.RuntimeException: never works)
```

If any of those fail with a None, the None will propogate to the yield.

Edit: Example method `f2` now throws an exception to show how to integrate them into this chain. Also changed to Try to make it more like your example.